# Firefox not showing alert boxes when run by Selenium

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium, popup

I have a Selenium test case where I do not provide values for some mandatory fields. When the user tries to submit that form I am expecting an alert box to show up. It does work as intended when testing manually.

However, when I run it from Selenium, it shows no alert box. I even tried sleeping the thread during the test for some long period so that the test Firefox window remain open. Then I manually tried clicking the button and it still doesn't work. I also tried opening the browser's developer console and running `alert('hi');` which too doesn't present the alert window. However, if I manually reload the window then it starts working. However, if I use Selenium code to reload the page (`getDriver().navigate().refresh()`) then too it doesn't work.

I also noted when this issue happens, all custom context menus too fail to open; browser provided context menu opens though. Any idea what could cause this issue?

Note that I have verified that in the Selenium WebDriver's Firefox profile, popups are not blocked.

```
@RunWith(OurUiRunner.class)
public class FormCheckIT extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void verifyThatTemplateValueIsDefaultedFromProperties() {
        gotoFormTypess(); // Opens list of form types
        WebElement link = getFormTypeLink(FORM_TYPE1);
        link.click();
        link = getFormLink(FORM1);
        link.click();

        waitForFormToLoad(FORM_LOAD_TIMEOUT);

        // There is a mandatory short description field on this form

        WebElement btnSubmit = findElement(By.id(SUBMIT_BTN_ID));
        Assert.assertNotNull("Submit button not found", btnSubmit);
        btnSubmit.click();
        // Expecting an alert box now

        Assert.assertTrue(Modal.exists());

    }

}
```

**Update**

After wasting so many ours, I checked out what exactly is `alert`. This turns out to be a code set by Selenium!

```
(function (msg) {     var alerts = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('__webdriverAlerts'));     alerts.push(msg);     window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverAlerts', JSON.stringify(alerts));   })
```

When I was using FF 32 I did this and it showed it was native `alert`, but now it shows the correct thing. (I am now using FF 22). This seems to be done by `com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.commands.AlertOverride`. Argh! How do I turn this off?